# How to control height of ellipse in radial gradient

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I am trying to use radial gradient for my background and below is the code.

```css
div {
  width: 778px;
  height: 100px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at top center, green, yellow 229px);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[image]

When I increase the height of the div it is appearing as

[image]

But we want to have fixed vertical radius for ellipse in radiant like below one

[image]

I tried to play around the background-size but the height of the div is not fixed. so I really cant set background-size.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's a radial, not an ellipsis gradient. you can wrap the div with another div and apply the yellow background there. then it will look like you want

Comment: Tried that too, but the content in the div is hiding behind the overlap div.

Comment: then put the content inside the overlap div but outside the normal div... without more info we can't really help you more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use values instead of ellipsis

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(220px 80px at top center, green, yellow);
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

> `<ending-shape>`
>
> Can be either `circle` or `ellipse`; determines whether the gradient’s ending shape is a circle or an ellipse, respectively. If  is omitted, the ending shape defaults to a circle if the `<size>` is a single `<length>`, and to an **ellipse otherwise**

> `<length-percentage>{2}`
>
> Gives the size of the ellipse explicitly. **The first value represents the horizontal radius**, **the second the vertical radius**. Percentages values are relative to the corresponding dimension of the gradient box. Negative values are invalid.

Reference: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#valdef-radial-gradient-ending-shape

---

Another alternative is to use a fixed `background-size`:

```css
body {
  background: 
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top center, green, yellow)
      top center/350px 80px no-repeat,
    yellow;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Is there any good GUI based software for website designing. To move elements, images, etc translates into code. @Temani Afif

Comment: @Pie they probably exist but I personnally write all the code myself. Never though about using (or even searching) such tools. I consider tools only for SVG complex shapes

Comment: Is there any offline version of official documentation for CSS which I can download. For example, PHP offers offline documentation in "chm" and pdf format. But I could not find any official offline documentation from w3.org for CSS. What do you use for offline documentation? @termani Afif

Comment: @Pie intresting question but I don't use an offline doc. Since CSS is about web, I always do this online with internet  so I don't really need any offline ressource. I doubt such think exist but you can probably scrap the w3.org website or the MDN one to have an offline version. Since it's a static website any scrapping tool can do it easily unless they implemented some securities to avoid scrapping. You will not have it PDF but a HTML website