# Why can't I horizontally scroll through a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added a shadow to the edges of the container through the `fade` classes. However, once I did this the scroll bar of the container stopped working and became unresponsive. I cannot scroll through the container without using the forwards and backwards buttons.

How do I fix this?

```js
const boxesView = document.querySelector('.boxes')
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
const fade = document.querySelector(".fade");

// btns
const forwardBtn = document.querySelector('#forwards')
const backBtn = document.querySelector('#backwards')

boxSize = boxes[0].clientWidth

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background', 'linear-gradient(90deg,#fff 0%, transparent 0% 85%,#fff 100%)')


forwardBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    boxesView.scrollBy(boxSize , 0)
})

backBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    boxesView.scrollBy(-boxSize , 0)
})

const firstBox = document.querySelector(".box:first-child");
const lastBox = document.querySelector(".box:last-child");
const firstAndLastBox = [firstBox,lastBox];

console.log(firstAndLastBox);
fade.classList.add("fade-right");

const observeFirst = new IntersectionObserver(entries=>{
// console.log(entries);
    const firstBoxDetails = entries[0];
    if(firstBoxDetails.isIntersecting){
        // document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--background', 'linear-gradient(90deg,#fff 0%, transparent 0% 85%,#fff 100%)')
        fade.classList.remove("fade-both-side");
        fade.classList.add("fade-right");
    }else{
        fade.classList.add('fade-both-side');
        fade.classList.remove("fade-right");
    }
    console.log(firstBoxDetails);
},{threshold:1});

const observeLast = new IntersectionObserver(entries=>{
    const lastBoxDetails = entries[0];
    if(lastBoxDetails.isIntersecting){
        fade.classList.remove("fade-both-side");
        fade.classList.add("fade-left");
    }else{
        fade.classList.add('fade-both-side');
        fade.classList.remove("fade-left");
    }
    console.log(lastBoxDetails);
},{threshold:1});
observeLast.observe(lastBox);
observeFirst.observe(firstBox);
```

```css
.boxes-container {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  position: relative;
}
.boxes::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: var(--background, );
}
.boxes .box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 332px;
  max-width: 332px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}
.boxes .box#last-box {
  padding-right: 2rem;
}
.boxes .box .img-container img {
  width: 322px;
  max-width: 322px;
  height: 200px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.boxes .box h6 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.boxes .box p {
  font-size: 14.5px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
}/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
.boxes{
  position: relative;
}
 
.fade-both-side::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  /* width: 30px; */
  height:100%;
  inset: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,red 0%, transparent 10% 92%,red 100%) ;
  /* background-color: red; */
}

.fade-left::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  /* width: 30px; */
  height:100%;
  inset: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,red 0%, transparent 10% 100%,red 99%) ;
  /* background-color: red; */
}
.fade-right::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  /* width: 30px; */
  height:100%;
  inset: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,red 0%, transparent 0% 92%,red 100%) ;
  /* background-color: red; */
}
```

```html
<button id="backwards">Back</button>
            <button id="forwards">Forwards</button>
            <div class="boxes-container">
                <div class="boxes">
                    <!-- box 1 -->
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="img-container">
                            <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/pictures/b6005f78-45e6-403a-bc1d-3351ae83d149.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h6>Why host on Airbnb?</h6>
                        <p>Hosts reveal what they love about sharing their space on Airbnb.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- box 2 -->
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="img-container">
                            <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/pictures/9ac19f4a-a59c-47f9-8223-09120b52cd2d.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h6>How to get started on Airbnb</h6>
                        <p>From creating your listing to prepping your space, learn how to start hosting.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- box 3 -->
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="img-container">
                            <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/pictures/4d0cc0ed-ad85-4efd-b98e-386d22ab195a.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h6>How to earn money on Airbnb</h6>
                        <p>Here's what every Host needs to know about pricing and payouts.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- box 4 -->
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="img-container">
                            <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/pictures/4efaca33-ca90-4d94-a79b-381cf0179355.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h6>Designing your space</h6>
                        <p>Designing your space for guests can be a quick way to boost your bookings.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- box 5 -->
                    <div class="box" id="last-box">
                        <div class="img-container">
                            <img src="https://a0.muscache.com/pictures/3cea79b0-79c3-4604-8fd9-7ef5cee4aa42.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h6>Secrets from a seasoned Superhost</h6>
                        <p>Superhost Nikki shares her tips, from setting up to standing out.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fade "></div>
                <!-- <div class="fade-left"></div>
                <div class="fade-right"></div> -->
            </div>
```

Comment: pointer-events: none; to the pseudo element

Comment: btw I advise you this CSS only solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59429383/8620333